# Determine if the sequence $a_n=\frac{4^n+5n!}{n!+2^n}$ converges or diverges. If the sequence converges, find its limit. State your reasoning.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, infinity

I've been able to solve similar questions but the introduction of the factorial is throwing me off. I know how factorials work as in $\;8!= 8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1\,,\;$ but I'm having trouble putting it into practice within the question. Thanks in advance.

$a_n=\dfrac{4^n+5n!}{n!+2^n}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Unformatted math is hard to read.  Do you mean $5\times (n!)$ or $(5n)!$ in the numerator?  [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.  Either way...which terms dominate here?

Comment: @Lahey, the sequence converges and the limit is $5$. If you want to know why, you should write in your post your efforts and attempts.

Comment: If the 5 is not included in the factorial, can we not just compare teh coefficients of the super-exponential terms and compute their ration? I'd guess here that since $n!$ grows far faster than the other terms, the answer would simply be $\frac{5(n!)}{n!}=5$.

Comment: Supposing the limit to be $5$ as others have said based on the factorials dominating the exponentials (think about how each one grows when $n$ increases by $1$ for large $n$) you may find it easier to prove this if you work in terms of the difference $a_n - 5,$ and prove that it goes to $0$ as $n$ gets large. There’s a bit of a link we can force from there to a common procedure in a related topic, but I don’t think I should say more until we’ve heard more about what you’ve tried.